# Immutable configuration of Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, immutables-library

I'm trying to find a way to use the [Immutables library](http://immutables.github.io/) to create data classes for holding the configuration of my Spring Boot application.

My data configuration class is:

```
@Value.Immutable
@JsonDeserialize(as = ImmutableAuthConfig.class)
public interface AuthConfig {
    String domain();
    String clientId();

    @Value.Redacted
    String clientSecret();
}
```

While the main configuration class is set up as

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties
public class Config {
    private ImmutableAuthConfig auth;

    public AuthConfig getAuth() {
        return auth;
    }

    public void setAuth(ImmutableAuthConfig auth) {
        this.auth = auth;
    }
}
```

I've tried some variations of using either `ImmutableAuthConfig` or just `AuthConfig` as a field, but nothing improved the situation. The configuration did not get picked up, and the `auth` field of the configuration remains `null` after application start-up.

Replacing the contents of the `AuthConfig` class with a traditional POJO solves the issue, but I would prefer an immutable object. Is there any way to convince Spring to interface with the classes generated by the Immutables library?

Comment: How are you creating the `AuthConfig` class and what is it supposed to be storing?

Comment: @Aris: The Immutables library is an annotation processor, that generates a factory-type class transparently in the background. Other serialization libraries (notably Jackson) can handle classes generated with the library merely by specifying the `@JsonDeserialize` annotation. I'm looking for something similar for whatever technique Spring is using for its configuration files.

Comment: Yes, I know that `Immutables` is. I haven't used it myself and thus I do not know 100% how this integrates with Spring. My main question is on how the `AuthConfig` values get generated. Are you reading them for a props file, are your retrieving them from a server?

Comment: @Aris: Apologies. Misunderstood your question. They're stored in a local YAML-file.

Comment: OK, so basically you want a single class that will store your configuration read from the respective properties which you'll then inject into some other bean. Is that correct?

Comment: @Aris: I want Spring to use the class generated by the Immutables framework as the storage of the configuration in the YAML file. It's a completely vanilla Spring-configuration issue, except that I want to replace the traditional POJOs with one generated by Immutables.

Comment: OK fair enough. But I still don't get why you're so keen on using Immutables. Spring can offer you a nice way of creating configuration services that entail more or less the same logic as what you want to achieve. Have taken a look at the usage of `@ConfigurationProperties`?

Comment: @Aris: To be honest, it's not exactly a "life-or-death"-issue. :) I love the Immutables library, and find externally read configuration to be an obvious use case for it. It also eliminates a ton of boilerplate. It's mostly aesthetics, but I got curious whether anyone else managed to do it, hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library's support for [modifiable classes](http://immutables.github.io/immutable.html#modifiable-classes) supplies an approach that is pretty close to what I was searching for.

```
@Value.Modifiable
public interface AuthConfig {
    String domain();
    String clientId();

    @Value.Redacted
    String clientSecret();
}
```

This creates the class `ModifiableAuthConfig` which provides an interface satisfying Spring's `JavaBeanBinder`, which is used for deserializing the configuration.

It's furthermore necessary to supply an instance of the mutable `AuthConfig` class, which Spring can then populate:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties
public class Config {
    private ImmutableAuthConfig auth = ModifiableAuthConfig.create();

    public AuthConfig getAuth() {
        return auth;
    }
}
```

Any use of the loaded configuration can subsequently happen through the `AuthConfig` interface, which doesn't provide mutating methods.